# Unity 2D animation running partially

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation, skeletal-animation

I have a 2D skeleton animation of human walk cycle - which is fine. I am trying hard to code that should STOP only hands animation but legs should not (on a player input - for example on space bar press) Is it possible to disable animation keyframes/curves/properties on some condition Or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Animation Layers feature](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html), and its masking of specific bones in particular?

Comment: It looks like this can be achieved with animation layer, I will play around with it and update. Thanks much